How to make inverted border using tailwind
How to create an inverted border radius using tailwind css using after and befor css properties, or any other alternatives to achive it

Tried with tailwind css, using befor and after css properties however i was not able to create it



<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div class="p-10 bg-gray-300">
  <div class="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gray-300">
  <div class="relative h-12 w-80 rounded-t-lg bg-gray-200">
    <div class="absolute -bottom-0 -left-24 h-10 w-24 rounded-br-lg bg-transparent shadow-[0.5rem_0_0_0] shadow-gray-200"></div>
    <div class="p-2 text-center font-mono text-xl">Inverted Border</div>
    <div class="absolute -bottom-0 -right-24 h-10 w-24  rounded-bl-lg bg-transparent shadow-[-0.5rem_0_0_0] shadow-gray-200"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-96 text-balance rounded-lg bg-gray-200 p-5 text-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Delectus praesentium eaque amet, vitae doloremque odio molestiae facilis temporibus? Tempora illum mollitia nihil fuga corrupti sint? Iusto nihil laborum rerum qui?</div>
</div>
</div>



